# How to say jetty-runner to not use random dir

Tags: jetty, jetty-9

I´m using jetty-runner to start my application. On every start it creates an new temp folder. I would like to avoid it. Here is my example:

`java -Djava.io.tempdir=webapp -jar jetty-runner-9.3.0.M2.jar wars\*.war context.xml`

When I start it, it creates a folder in webapp `jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-mywar.war-_-any-2227787194488516977.dir`. So it uses the right syntax `"jetty-"+host+"-"+port+"-"+resourceBase+"-_"+context+"-"+virtualhost+"-"+randomdigits+".dir"`.

My question ist how to avoid it, to generate random digits. I would like to reuse webapps and only genreate new one, if my wars changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So how I see, there is no chance to avoid generation of randomdigits :-(
See source code:
[org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/6cabf8452e0e08f395a08916397ab6a7e602ff7c/jetty-webapp/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/WebInfConfiguration.java#L646)

Answer (score 0):

By default, Jetty will create a temporary directory for each web application. The name of the directory will be of the form:

```
"jetty-"+host+"-"+port+"-"+resourceBase+"-_"+context+"-"+virtualhost+"-"+randomdigits+".dir"
```

Each time when you start jetty, it use to check the war file with existing deployment folder and If it identifiyes war file is changed, jetty deletes old depolyment folder and deploy the changed war as fresh. You need not worry about the deployment.

Comment: You are right, but i don´t change my war file and every time jetty-runner creates new folder. Is it possible, that jetty-runner behaves in this way? I don´t found any parameter to avoid this behaviour.

Comment: No it should not, I dont use jetty runner, using recent version of jetty 9.1. and webapp folders is being created under work folder. Are you sure each time recreates new folder ?

Comment: Yes it creates everytime a new folder. But it depends how I _close_ my application. If I send an exit cmd by `Ctrl+C` jetty shotdown the application and removes my folder. If i kill my application by cling cmd window, jetty has no chance to remove temp folder. Unfortunately it does´n help me. Iy would like to resue my temp folder.